# The natural representation of $SO(n)$ is irreducible for $n\ge 3$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

The natural representation $(\pi,\mathbb C^n)$ of $SO(n)$ is the one for which

$$\pi (g)z = g^{-1}z$$

for $g\in SO(n)$ and $z \in \mathbb C^n$ (the product $g^{-1}z$ is just the usual matrix product).

(Or maybe the representation is $gz$, not $g^{-1}z$. The exercise isn't clear what it meant. I don't think this changes much?)

I'm supposed to show this representation is irreducible if $n\ge 3$.

As a first part of the exercise, I proved that given two pairs $v_1, v_2$ and $u_1,u_2$ of orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ then there exists a $x\in SO(n)$ for which

$$ xv_1 = u_1\\ xv_2=u_2 $$

Also, I proved that for all elements $c$ in the centralizer of $SO(n)$, the following holds:

$$\langle cv_1,v_2 \rangle = \langle cu_1,u_2 \rangle $$

But I have no idea what these preliminary steps have to do with the original problem.

Comment: The $SO(n)$ here is the real group I'm guessing, since you're talking about orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? There's also an $SO(n)$ defined over the complex numbers which is very different so you might want to clarify which one you mean.

Answer (score 2):

We want to show that the centralizer only consists of elements $\lambda\cdot I_n$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Schur's lemma then immediately yields that the representation is irreducible.

First, we note that we can express an arbitrary vector $x$ as $\sum_{i=1}^n \langle x,e_i\rangle e_i$, because $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ form an orthonormal basis. We want to use this expression to find out how $T$ works on the basis vectors. In other words, we want to compute $\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle$ for all $i\neq j$. However, we note that by the previous exercise we have $$\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle=\langle T(-e_i),-e_j\rangle=-\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle $$Hence,$\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle=0$ for all $i\neq j$, so we already know that $T$ is a diagonal matrix. It remains to show that all the diagonal elements must equal each other. Consider the matrix $P_{i,j}$, which is the identity matrix but with rows (or columns) $i$ and $j$ swapped. Using the fact that $P_{i,j}$, or $-P_{i,j}$, is in $SO(n)$, and that $TP_{i,j}=P_{i,j}T$, we get that $T_{i,i}=T_{j,j}$. We can repeated this argument and conclude that every diagonal element has to be the same.

Comment: "We want to show that the centralizer only consists of elements $\lambda\cdot I_n$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Schur's lemma then immediately yields that the representation is irreducible". From what I understood, Schurs lemma says that if $(\pi,V)$ is unitary and $End_G(V)$ consists of $\lambda \cdot I$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ then $\pi$ is irreducible. How does $End_G(V)$ related to the centralizer?

Comment: The centralizer is exactly this space $End_G(V)$, it contains of all the elements $T$ such that $T$ commutes with every action of $V$, which is the natural representation of $SO(n)$.

Comment: The centralizer is the set of elements that commute with all elements. $End_G(V)$ is the set of endomorphisms $A$ which satisfy $\pi(g)A\pi(g)^{-1}=A$, and then $\pi(g)A\pi(g)^{-1}=gAg^{-1}$, so $gA=Ag$?

Comment: The centralizer of $SO(n)$ is the set of elements $T$ such that $Tg=gT$ for every $g$ in $SO(n)$. The space $End_G(V)$.  is exactly the set of endomorphisms $T$ such that $T\pi(g)=\pi(g)T$ for every $g$ in $SO(n)$. However, the representation is just the standard representation so we have $\pi(g)=g$. This shows that the space of intertwiners and the centralizer are the same.

Comment: I think you meant :   $$\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle=\langle T(-e_i),e_j\rangle=-\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle $$, otherwise we get just  $$\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle=\langle T(-e_i),-e_j\rangle=\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle $$ which doesn't say anything