# Space End$_G(V)$ of intertwiners from $(V,\pi)$ to itself and the centralizer of $SO(n,\Bbb R)$ in $M(n,\Bbb R)$ coincide

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

**For the natural representation $\pi(g): V \to V: v \mapsto gv$ of $G=SO(n,\Bbb R)$ on $V= \Bbb C^n$ I want to prove that the space End$_G(V)$ of intertwiners from $(V,\pi)$ to itself and the centralizer of $SO(n,\Bbb R)$ in $M(n,\Bbb R)$ coincide**  ($n\ge 3$ if that is relevant)

I have the following argument:

The centralizer $C$ of $SO(n, \Bbb R)$ is the set of elements $T\in M(n,\Bbb R)$ such that $Tg=gT$ $\forall g \in SO(n,\Bbb R)$.

End$_G(V)$ is exactly the set of endomorphisms $T$ such that $T\circ \pi (g)=\pi (g)T\forall g 
 \in SO(n,\Bbb R)$
The representation is just the standard representation $\pi(g)=g$. This shows that the space of intertwiners and the centralizer coincide.

**But I wonder,** This equivalence  of $C$ and End$_G(V)$ relies on each element in End$_G(V)$, being represented/isomorphic (? I don't know how should I best phrase  it ) to the corresponding $n\times n$ matrix that represents the linear map.

Looking  at the centralizer definition the matrix should be in $M(n,\Bbb R)$ but looking at the End$_G(V)$ definition  since it's a map from $\Bbb C^n$ to $\Bbb C^n$,I think the matrix is in $M(n,\Bbb C)$, isn't it? What could guarantee that this matrix is actually in  $M(n,\Bbb R)$ ? Unless I write the complex numbers as two-column vectors, but then it is not an action on $\Bbb C^n$ anymore but on $\Bbb R^{2n}$ and the matrix gets size $2n\times 2n$.  Then I can not state the equivalence that I am after anymore.  Could you help me clarify this?

**Note** : I need this argument to work to prove that $\pi$ is irreducible, for $(n\ge 3)$. Specifically, it is needed to show that  End$_G(V) \subseteq \Bbb CId_V$ and apply  Schur's lemma (see [The natural representation of $SO(n)$ is irreducible for $n\ge 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747122/the-natural-representation-of-son-is-irreducible-for-n-ge-3/3422942#3422942) )